# Deal with a pop-up window of a plug-in in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, popup

I'm using a plug-in in Eclipse. This plug-in provides a feature to the Eclipse menu (when I right-click). I would like to capture the value that a user selects. Is there anyway in Java to do that since this added feature is not added by my project but by the plug-in ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the debugger feature in eclispe.. set toggle points and run the application in debugger mode.. this way you can trace the values coming in after each statement is executed..

Check this image 
[Eclipse debugger http://s19.postimage.org/6x3yy8a43/eclipseimage.png](http://s19.postimage.org/6x3yy8a43/eclipseimage.png)

The blue dot refers the toggle breakpoint.. use the mouse left click to place it on the statement u like... and run the project in debugger mode see top of the image..

press F6 to execute next statement in the debugger mode

Hope this helps

Cheers

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to Eclipse. Can you explain that in a detailed steps?